# Scrape all html between tags

Tags: .net, regex

Can't seem to get this after hours of searching and trial and error.  I'm trying to return the text between two html tags.  The problem is that the text spans multiple lines.  Here's an example.  If someone could figure out a regex to match all content between the html tags.

```
<section id="mysection">
The text always starts on the line after the opening section tag.
It can be anything and even span multiple lines.
The closing tag always comes after the last line of text.
</section>
```

I've tried

```
Regex.Match(html, "<section id=\"mysection\">/s+(.*?)/s+</section>");
```

with some success but only worked if there was one line of text and not if there we're line breaks 
 and such.  Using the example above, I want it to match "The text always starts on the line after the opening section tag.
    It can be anything and even span multiple lines.
    The closing tag always comes after the last line of text."

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2246674

Comment: @user2246674 You beat me to it :P

Comment: The Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character
http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: Oops (my previous and now deleted comment was wrong), see `Singleline` in [RegexOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) for why `.` stops working with newlines - as well as what option would make it accept newlines ..

Comment: assume it is xml and parse it like the previous comment. Or use something like casperjs to create a fake dom of the page, so that you can access the content of the page without requiring a browser.

Comment: SO should introduce a badge for asking html regex questions.

Comment: Try using `"(?s)section id=\"mysection\">/s+(.*?)/s+</section>"`

Comment: RegexOptions.Multiline might help

Comment: @M.UtkuALTINKAYA, multiline affects the behavior of `^` and `$`, not `.`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Regex.Match(html, "\\<section id=\"mysection\"\\>(.*?)\\</section\\>", 
            RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

According to the documentation for RegexOptions.Singleline:

> Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n).

Also, your angle brackets need to be escaped.